# FB Connect - Can It Be Used to share message with multiple users?

Tags: facebook

I suppose the answer is pretty simple, but i cant find conclusive answer either way.

Is it possible to use facebook to log in a user, fetch their friends, allow them to select them and then post to their profiles in turn, even if that means firing up a custom modal with html to select from the list of users friends before passing the IDs on to the publishStream function in a loop.

Any response would be dandy. Thanks guys and gals.

Answer (score 0):

If you post to the logged-in user's stream, you have no control over which friends see it in their own streams.

Alternatively, you can send facebook notifications to friends that were selected, subject to the daily notification limit imposed on your app by facebook.  Be aware that facebook is phasing out noficiations.

Comment: Klochner -

Thanks ... well it looks like FB phased out everything last night and switched to what I was using before publishStream, the problem is that you can only post to a single user/actor at a time, and I dont think a batch sequencer object can be passed, and looping through 'actors' and generating a popup kinda sucks.  The best alternative is the sharer.php link but that doesn't provide the benefit of attachments etc.

Still trying to find a clean solution, but will definiitely post code and how to when done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you said. Just get the list of user IDs before hand using your custom dialog you mentioned. Then call the FB.ui function repeatedly, populating the "to" parameter with each friend ID.

```
    FB.ui(
        {
         method: 'feed',
         to: #,
         name: 'name of post',
         link: 'http://link.com',
         picture: 'http://link.com/image.jpg',
         description: 'descriptive text',
         },
        function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert('Post was published.'+response);
            } else {
                alert('Post was not published.'+response);
            }
        }
    );
```